# can i append some php to a form action?

Tags: php, html

i have the following which is within a foreach loop and lists the unique code as a link:

```
<a href="" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" >
  <?php echo $uniqueCode1?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
</a>
<form id="message_area" style="display:none" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
 </form>
```

i want to pass the id of the uniquecode i clicked on but $id_to = the first link's id i also tried to pass $id_to as a hidden field inside the form tag but still it takes the id of the first uniquecode link regardless of which link i click on

please help?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

You messed up with `"`.

Try with:

```
<form id="message_area" style="display:none" method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

The form action can be another PHP script which can read POSTed variables.  Add id as a hidden field to POST.

Comment: thank you i corrected the " and also tried it with hidden field but the problem comes in: i have a <a> tag outside the form tag which lists unique code links,via a foreach, the one i clicked on is the on's id i want to pass at the moment it is passing the first one no matter which one i click on...i will repost my code to include the <a> tag